# Creating a cancel button... how to completely abort a request in Node/Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I want to create a "Cancel" button in my app. The request the button is meant to cancel contains a `Promise.all` that usually takes a few minutes to complete due to API rate limiting on the other end.

If I have a route like this:

```
router.get('/api/my_route', (req, res, next) => {

//imagine this takes about 2 minutes to complete and send back the 200.
//The user changes their mind and wants to cancel it at the 1 minute mark.

  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
    .then(first_response => first_response.json())
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(item => 
       fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
       .then(second_response => second_response.json())
       .then(value => console.log(value))
      )))
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200);   
    });
});
```

How do you cancel this and completely abort it in the middle of making the Promise requests?

Comment: You can set up two promises in your callback to `router.get`: one that does the existing `fetch().then...`, and one that waits (or repeatedly checks) for the `cancel` event (such as a button click) to fire. You can respond to whichever one happens first and ignore the other by using `Promise.race`. If the `cancel` event never happens, the `fetch...` sequence wins. (Once the promise is called, it can't really be 'canceled', but you can choose to just disregard the result.)

Comment: for instance, the native nodejs request has an abort method

Comment: @JaromandaX sure you can - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#request-cancellation-with-abortsignal

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - OK, so, it's not like fetch in browsers then :p

Comment: @JaromandaX you can cancel fetch in browsers too :]

Comment: really @BenjaminGruenbaum - I've lost touch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) in order to abort the fetch requests and listen to the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2) event on the request to know the client closed the connection:

```
router.get('/api/my_route', (req, res, next) => {
  // we create a new AbortController to abort the fetch request
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;

  req.on('close', err => { // if the request is closed from the other side
    controller.abort(); // abort our own requests
  })


  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums", {signal})
    .then(first_response => first_response.json())
    .then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(item => 
       fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {signal})
       .then(second_response => second_response.json())
       .then(value => console.log(value))
      )))
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: req.on('close',...) not firing for me

Answer (score 0):

Promises themselves do not have a mechanism for cancellation. You could potentially send another api request to the remote server to cancel the original request, but if it's rate limited, it suggests that it's an old server that might not be easy to change.